# Retrieve Custom Setting values

Tags: visualforce-component

Can we get custom setting field values in visualforce component without using controller

Comment: List or hierarchy?

Answer (score 3):

For a List Custom Setting, you can't directly access the settings directly by a formula. For a hierarchy setting, you can use `$Setup.CustomSettingName__c.FieldName__c`. See [$Setup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_setup.htm) for more details on how this works.

If you want to insert/update/delete List settings, however, you can use [remote objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_using.htm). I suggest you read the manual for more information. Note that this only allows you to access the settings by JavaScript; you won't be able to use them in formulas.